# Why are my copy and paste controls getting clipped?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

My copy and paste controls (blue dots to select text) are getting clipped in my UITextView.  How do I prevent this from happening?

[alt text http://lingsdesigns.com/public/copyControls.png](http://lingsdesigns.com/public/copyControls.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you have a view on top of the textview, or something that's clipping the pin. Are you drawing the gray areas just above the textview? If so, raise the textview to the top of the view hierarchy.

Did you by chance set negative content insets for the textview? (IB wouldn't even let me set negative content insets, but perhaps it's possible programmatically)